# How to create a Rician random variable?

Tags: python, statistics, sympy

I'm trying to model a signal detection problem using Sympy, and need two random variables.  One with a Rayleigh distribution to model noise, and one with a Rician distribution to model signal+noise.  Sympy [provides a Rayleigh distribution](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/stats.html), but not a Rician-- or at least not one by that name.

What's the best way of creating one?  Does it exist under a different name?  Is there a way to manipulate existing distributions into a Rician?

---

Following advice from @asmeurer, I've implemented my own Rice distribution, like so:

```
from sympy.stats.crv_types import rv
from sympy.stats.crv import SingleContinuousDistribution

class RicianDistribution(SingleContinuousDistribution):
    _argnames=('nu','sigma')
    @property
    def set(self): return Interval(0,oo)

    def pdf(self,x):
        nu,sigma=self.nu, self.sigma
        return (x/sigma**2)*exp(-(x**2+nu**2)/(2*sigma**2))*besseli(0,x*nu/sigma**2)

def Rician(name,nu,sigma):
    return rv(name,RicianDistribution,(nu,sigma))
```

The distribution seems to match both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution) and [Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rice.html#scipy.stats.rice), but oddly I'm getting different results than Scipy.  I'll ask that question separately ([asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33049370/2571165)).

As a side note, the following line makes it possible to lambdify the density function, which includes a Bessel function:

```
printing.lambdarepr.LambdaPrinter._print_besseli=(lambda self,expr: 'i0(%s)'%expr.argument)
```

It's not generalized to all Bessel functions, but works for the zero order modified Bessel of the first kind used in the Rician distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the pdf function, it's easy to create a new distribution with sympy.stats. Take a look at the existing distributions in the [sympy source](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/stats/crv_types.py). You just need to subclass `SingleContinuousDistribution` and define some methods. For example, here is the normal distribution (with the docstrings removed):

```
class NormalDistribution(SingleContinuousDistribution):
    _argnames = ('mean', 'std')

    @staticmethod
    def check(mean, std):
        _value_check(std > 0, "Standard deviation must be positive")

    def pdf(self, x):
        return exp(-(x - self.mean)**2 / (2*self.std**2)) / (sqrt(2*pi)*self.std)

    def sample(self):
        return random.normalvariate(self.mean, self.std)


def Normal(name, mean, std):
    return rv(name, NormalDistribution, (mean, std))
```

Comment: Maybe the form _X = ContinuousRV(x, exp(-(x - mean)**2 / (2*std**2)) / (sqrt(2*pi)*std))_ is easier to write, though parametrization is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate the Rice from chi-squared and Poisson.  See any thorough Rice discussion, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution:

> Another case where Rice(nu,sigma) comes from the following steps:
>
> 1. Generate P having a Poisson distribution with parameter (also mean, for a Poisson) lambda = nu^2 / (2*sigma^2).
> 2. Generate X having a chi-squared distribution with 2P + 2 degrees of freedom.
> 3. Set R = sigma * sqrt(X).

Comment: I'd seen that description, but don't fully understand it.  Would you be able to show that workflow in Sympy code?  Step 2 in particular seems odd to me: it seems to imply that the parameter to the Chi Squared distribution is itself a random variable (using P from step 1)?

Comment: I don't program in sympy; sorry.  Yes, the input is a random variable.  The output is a distribution of one extra dimension, taking as input the entire distribution (value x probability) and producing an output of (chi-distribution x probability).