# Why doesn't my Rician in Sympy match the Rician in Scipy?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, sympy

I've tried to create a Sympy continuous random variable with a Rician distribution.  With thanks to help from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32981363/2571165), it seems that the best approach is to subclass `SingleContinuousDistribution`.  I've implemented a distribution that appears to be in agreement between [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution) and [Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rice.html#scipy.stats.rice), however I am not getting the same results as Scipy.

What follows is code that implements the random variable, extracts its symbolic distribution and converts it to a Numpy representation through `lambdify` then plots my distribution against the PDF of the Scipy `rician` distribution.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import stats
from scipy import stats as scst
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sympy.stats.crv_types import rv
from sympy.stats.crv import SingleContinuousDistribution

class RicianDistribution(SingleContinuousDistribution):
    _argnames=('nu','sigma')
    @property
    def set(self): return Interval(0,oo)

    def pdf(self,x):
        nu,sigma=self.nu, self.sigma
        return (x/sigma**2)*exp(-(x**2+nu**2)/(2*sigma**2))*besseli(0,x*nu/sigma**2)

def Rician(name,nu,sigma):
    return rv(name,RicianDistribution,(nu,sigma))

#this line helps lambdify convert the sympy Bessel to a numpy Bessel
printing.lambdarepr.LambdaPrinter._print_besseli=(lambda self,expr: 'i0(%s)'%expr.argument)

x=Symbol('x')  #parameter for density function

sigma=3; pr=4

#create the symbolic Rician and numeric Rician
SpN=Rician('R',pr,sigma)  #signal plus noise
Rsci=scst.rice(pr,scale=sigma)

fx=lambdify(x,stats.density(SpN)(x),'numpy')

xs=np.linspace(0,25,1000)
plt.plot(xs,fx(xs),'b');
plt.plot(xs,Rsci.pdf(xs),'r');
```

I would expect the results to match, but they don't appear to:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of the Rice distribution in [`scipy.stats.rice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rice.html) uses a slightly different parameterization than the parameterization described in [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution).

To make your plots agree, change this line

```
Rsci=scst.rice(pr,scale=sigma)
```

to

```
Rsci=scst.rice(pr/sigma, scale=sigma)
```

---

Here's a longer explanation:

The PDF shown on wikipedia is

[image: wikipedia pdf]

The PDF in the docstring of `scipy.stats.rice` is

[image: scipy.stats.rice pdf]

However, that formula does not show the `scale` parameter that all of the continuous distributions in scipy have.  (It also doesn't show the location parameter `loc`, but I'll assume there is no interest in using a Rice distribution with a nonzero location.)  To create the formula that includes the scale parameter, we use the standard scale family of a PDF:

[image: scale formula]

So the scipy PDF is actually

[image: scipy pdf with scale]

If we make the identifications

[image: parameter mapping]

we obtain the PDF shown in the wikipedia article.

In your code, your parameter `pr` is ν, so to convert to scipy's parameterization, you must use `b = pr / sigma`.

Comment: Thank you for the added detail, that really made it clear.  I'd read the scale factor description, but it hadn't sunk in that I needed to adjust b to make it work.