# Working with statistical expressions in SymPy without specifying distribution

Tags: python, sympy

Is it possible to manipulate statistical expressions in `SymPy` without specifying the distributions of random variables?

For example, I would like to work with two random variables, `X` and `Y`, and be able to ask `SymPy` to expand the expression `Var(X + Y)`, getting the answer `Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2 Cov(X,Y)`.

I would also like to be able to put restrictions on the distributions of `X` and `Y`, for example telling SymPy that `Cov(X, Y) = 0`.

Is this at all possible in `SymPy`? If not, is there another package that can do it?

Comment: It looks like sympy.stats is built around having explicit distributions with explicit pdfs. I think the closest you can get is creating a custom distribution with pdf `f(x)`, where `f = Function('f')` is an undefined function.

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981363/how-to-create-a-rician-random-variable/32998623#32998623. I'm not sure if you can derive this identity or not.

Comment: _variance_ in _sympy.stats_ will try to evaluate the integral, it does not construct an expression. You may try _variance(X, evaluate=False)_, but this will only result in an unevaluated integral. I think we need to define a _Variance_ (capital V) class to mean the symbolic formula.

Comment: I realize this is probably not a trivial thing to implement, but it would be very useful for econometricians to have the ability to work with variance, and covariance, and general expectations expressions with minimal structure on the random variables.

Comment: Yes, I agree. We should implement it.

Comment: SymPy's development version now supports symbolic variance and covariance. It will be included in the next full version.

Answer (score 1):

As @Francesco Bonazzi stated the new version 1.10 allows for this:

```
#Version of sympy should be >=1.10
from sympy import *
from sympy.stats import Variance, Expectation
from sympy.stats.rv import RandomSymbol

#Create variables as random symbols:
X = RandomSymbol('X')
Y = RandomSymbol('Y')

#You can also create constants (for generalization)
a,b,c = symbols('a b c')

#And then calculate variance:
Variance(a*X + b*Y + c).expand()
```

which results in:

```
a^2 Var(X) + 2abCov(X,Y) + b^2Var(Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import itertools
from sympy.stats.rv import RandomSymbol
from sympy.stats import *

class Variance(Expr):

    def __new__(cls, arg, **kwargs):
        return Expr.__new__(cls, arg)

    def doit(self, **kwargs):
        return variance(self.args[0], **kwargs)

    def var_expansion(self):
        if isinstance(self.args[0], Add):
            nonrv = []
            rv = []
            for a in self.args[0].args:
                if isinstance(a, RandomSymbol):
                    rv.append(a)
            variances = Add(*map(Variance, rv))
            map_to_covar = lambda x: Function("Covariance")(*x)
            covariances = Add(*map(map_to_covar, itertools.combinations(rv, 2)))
            return variances + covariances
        return self
```

The function *.var_expansion()* does what you wish.

Example:

```
In [2]: z = Symbol('z')

In [3]: X = Normal('X', 3, 4)

In [5]: Y = Normal('Y', 1, 2)

In [6]: Variance(X)
Out[6]: Variance(X)

In [7]: Variance(X + z)
Out[7]: Variance(z + X)

In [8]: Variance(X).var_expansion()
Out[8]: Variance(X)

In [9]: Variance(X + z).var_expansion()
Out[9]: Variance(X)

In [10]: Variance(X + Y).var_expansion()
Out[10]: Covariance(X, Y) + Variance(X) + Variance(Y)
```

Unfortunately, much more work is required to implement all of its properties.

To perform the calculation of the variance:

```
In [14]: Variance(X).doit()
Out[14]: 16
```

To get the integral expression:

```
In [18]: Variance(X).doit(evaluate=False)
Out[18]: 
∞                                                       
⌠                                                       
⎮                                       2               
⎮        ⎛    ∞                        ⎞                
⎮        ⎜    ⌠                        ⎟                
⎮        ⎜    ⎮                   2    ⎟                
⎮        ⎜    ⎮           -(X - 3)     ⎟           2    
⎮        ⎜    ⎮           ──────────   ⎟   -(X - 3)     
⎮        ⎜    ⎮    ___        32       ⎟   ──────────   
⎮    ___ ⎜    ⎮  ╲╱ 2 ⋅X⋅ℯ             ⎟       32       
⎮  ╲╱ 2 ⋅⎜X - ⎮  ─────────────────── dX⎟ ⋅ℯ             
⎮        ⎜    ⎮            ___         ⎟                
⎮        ⎜    ⎮        8⋅╲╱ π          ⎟                
⎮        ⎜    ⌡                        ⎟                
⎮        ⎝    -∞                       ⎠                
⎮  ────────────────────────────────────────────────── dX
⎮                           ___                         
⎮                       8⋅╲╱ π                          
⌡                                                       
-∞
```